# mod_rewrite on optional Get parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]{1,2})/?$  /category.php?id=$1
```

^That rewrites to:
`/category/<number>/`

What should i add for the OPTIONAL page number? `category.php?id=2&page=2`. Means `/category/<number>/` is equal to `/category/<number>/page-1/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use pagination you will have to add an extra param in the URL. If you want `/category/<number>/` to go to a specific ID and `/category/<number>/` to go to a specific page you will have a conflict.

What you have to do is this:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/?$  /category.php?id=$1&page=1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/page\-([0-9]+)/?$  /category.php?id=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

This means if you use `/category/<number>/` it goes to a specific ID and loads the page #1 and then you can load a specific page using `/category/<number>/<page>/`.

Comment: one question though, does `([0-9]+)` include two-three digit numbers? thanks!

Comment: this means one or more number